# SharePoint JavaScript REST Api, how is the access token passed

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, rest

I have the following code in my SharePoint add-in (SharePoint Online).  Simple code just to load the list items, the code works fine

```
    $.ajax({
        url: appweburl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('MyList')/items",
        type: "GET",
        headers: { "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose" },
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {
            alert('Successfully obtained data.');
        },
        error: function (data) {
            alert(data);
        }
    });
```

My confusion is, I am not passing any access token and from what I know the access token is required to let the add-in access data.  So how is this working?

Answer (score 5):

The browser passes over the FedAuth cookie with the XHR request, and that authenticates you.

Comment: But `FedAuth` only appears in some condition (FBA, ADFS etc), In my configuration there's no FedAuth, do you know how the rest API is authenticated in SharePoint in that case (windows claims + NTLM)?, see my post http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/184214/why-sharepoint-2013-does-not-have-fedauth-cookie-in-some-condition

Comment: If you're using NTLM it'll be using the Bearer HTTP Header.

Comment: In my environment the SharePoint pages are authenticated in standard NTLM procedure (server respond with `WWWAuthenticate: NTLM` and so on), however, after authenticated, I cannot find any token like things in subsequent successful api call. (I have manually cleared cookie `WSS_KeepSessionAuthenticated`), I wonder how SharePoint authenticate/associate these api call with current user. I can post a new question if my description is not clear here and invite you, Thanks a lot!